# Quick Chunk Creation

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a chunk. It works but is slow. That's what I'm doing.

1. Describe the cube

```
vertices = [(-block_size / 2, -block_size / 2, block_size / 2),
            (block_size / 2, -block_size / 2, block_size / 2), (block_size / 2, block_size / 2, block_size / 2),
            (-block_size / 2, block_size / 2, block_size / 2),
            (-block_size / 2, block_size / 2, -block_size / 2),
            (-block_size / 2, -block_size / 2, -block_size / 2),
            (block_size / 2, -block_size / 2, -block_size / 2),
            (block_size / 2, block_size / 2, -block_size / 2)]

indices = [(0, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2),
           (1, 7, 2), (1, 6, 7),
           (6, 5, 4), (4, 7, 6),
           (3, 4, 5), (3, 5, 0),
           (3, 7, 4), (3, 2, 7),
           (0, 6, 1), (0, 5, 6)]

tex_coord_vertices = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)]
tex_coord_indices = [(0, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2),
                     (0, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2),
                     (0, 1, 2), (2, 3, 0),
                     (2, 3, 0), (2, 0, 1),
                     (0, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2),
                     (3, 1, 2), (3, 0, 1), ]

normals = [(0, 0, 1) * 6,
           (1, 0, 0) * 6,
           (0, 0, -1) * 6,
           (-1, 0, 0) * 6,
           (0, 1, 0) * 6,
           (0, -1, 0) * 6, ]
normals = np.array(normals, dtype='f4').reshape(36, 3)
```

2. I make a 2f 3f 3f dataset out of it

```
def get_data(vertices, indices):
    data = [vertices[ind] for triangle in indices for ind in triangle]
    return np.array(data, dtype='f4')
```

```
vertex_data_local = self.get_data(vertices, indices)
tex_coord_data = self.get_data(tex_coord_vertices, tex_coord_indices)
vertex_data_local = np.hstack([normals, vertex_data_local])
vertex_data_local = np.hstack([tex_coord_data, vertex_data_local])
```

3.Now when I have an array of cube data I create an array of cube center coordinates for the chunk

```
chunk_size = Settings.CHUNK_SIZE * Settings.CHUNK_SIZE * Settings.CHUNK_SIZE
coords = np.empty([chunk_size, 8])

index = 0
for x in range(Settings.CHUNK_SIZE):
    for y in range(Settings.CHUNK_SIZE):
                for z in range(Settings.CHUNK_SIZE):
                    if self.m_pBlocks[x][y][z].is_active():
                        coords[index] = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, x * block_size, y * block_size, z * block_size)
                        index = index + 1
```

4. Get chunk data array

```
vertex_data = np.empty([chunk_size * 36, 8])
index = 0
for idx, obj in enumerate(coords):
    for ind, obj_row in enumerate(vertex_data_local):
        # print(np.add(arr, obj_row))
        vertex_data[index] = np.add(obj, obj_row)
        index = index + 1
vertex_data = np.array(vertex_data, dtype='f4')
```

It seems to be possible to write in C and add it as a library. Any other ideas?